# Мини чат в один PHP фаил

Tags: php, chat

Если у кого то есть такое в готовом виде покажите? Спасибо.

Пожелания: 
1) база данных на текстовых файлах (UTF-8)
2) возможность самоочищения чата 
3) настройка (в коде) сколько показывать сообщений

Не обязательно:
1) регистрация
2) комнаты
3) смалики

PS Если знаете ссылку буду рад.

Comment: мне кажется свой чат будет легче создать для ваших нужд, чем использовать сторонний

Answer (score 1):

В один файл вряд ли всё поместится, но можно поискать на сайте
[phpclasses](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6200-PHP-Simple-Web-and-MySQL-based-chat-system.html)

Comment: Конкатенировать файлы в один можно без особых проблем. Кроме того, существуют phar-архивы. Но вот зачем это условие автору - понятия не имею.

Comment: скорее всего чтобы было проще заинклюдить :)